# Converting cshtml file to raw html in ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

Can I convert a cshtml file into raw html file? I'm searching for it but couldn't find any good solution.

Comment: Is [the effect in this picture](https://i.imgur.com/wRff1OZ.png) what you want ?

Comment: No,I want exactly same output as cshtml file.

Comment: Web servers like IIS do that. You do not have to write any code.

Comment: Does below answer useful to u ?

Answer (score 3):

Found this solution a few months ago at SO.

```csharp
public class CustomViewRendererService
{
    private readonly IRazorViewEngine _razorViewEngine;
    private readonly ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;

    public CustomViewRendererService(
        IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider)
    {
        _razorViewEngine = razorViewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
    }

    public async Task<string> RenderViewToStringAsync(ControllerContext actionContext, string viewPath,
        object model)
    {
        var viewEngineResult = _razorViewEngine.GetView(viewPath, viewPath, false);

        if (viewEngineResult.View == null || (!viewEngineResult.Success))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException($"Unable to find view '{viewPath}'");
        }

        var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), actionContext.ModelState);
        viewDictionary.Model = model;

        var view = viewEngineResult.View;
        var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider);

        using var sw = new StringWriter();
        var viewContext =
            new ViewContext(actionContext, view, viewDictionary, tempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
        await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Using inside controller:

```csharp
const string templatePath = "~/Views/Email/Test.cshtml";
string msg = await _viewService.RenderViewToStringAsync(ControllerContext, templatePath, new EmailConfirmationBuilderViewModel(url));
```